# Can we have both ajax and jquery scripts in one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, chart.js

I am working on an interactive project where interface showing graphs and related data to each graphs.
I am thinking a way that, How can i get data from server and stylize the data and display those in graphs?

I am not sure. where can we use both ajax and Jquery in one function or not?

For example we can create new elements with jquery like this:

```
function set_value() {
    var data2 = document.getElementById('div_id');
    data2.style.width = "100%";
    data2.innerText = "Economics";
    var delay = 700;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var element = document.createElement("i");
        element.style.cssFloat = "right";
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('100%'));
        data2.appendChild(element);
    }, delay);
}
```

I want to get those percentage values from Database and i am not sure. how to do this?
please someone help me. 
thank you!

Comment: First I DO NOT see any `ajax` calls. Second, if you are using `jQuery`, do not use `getElementById` or `.style.with`. Use consistent approach

Comment: i am sorry Mr Rajesh about those codes but what  i want to get is what i am talking about. the above example is just a simulation where i want to sent my idea to others.

Comment: By `jQuery` if you mean styling/DOM manipulation, no. Ajax calls are async. Compiler will not wait for its response. You can pass `DOM manipulation` logic as a callback to ajax or look into `promise`. Also its better if you split code into multiple functions as its more maintainable and more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Considering "url" to be the service returning percentage value in json form.

```
$.ajax({
   url:url,
   success:function(response) {
     call_your_function(response.percentage);
   }
});
```

Also as mentioned by @Rajesh use jquery methods to style the elements.